# Change image on AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm currently using an `AVPlayerViewController` solely to play audio and not video. With just an audio source, the background image defaults to the quicktime logo("image below"). Is there a way to change this background image?

[image]

Comment: why not use AVAudioPlayer ?

Comment: I'd like to use an AVPlayerViewController because it provides simple controls (slider, play/pause btns, etc). Is there something like an "AVAudioPlayerViewController" I can use that will provide controls?